# Newbie: object or hash?

Tags: javascript, terminology

If I define something like following:

```
var groups={
   'group_one': ['red','green','blue'],
   'group_two': ['yellow','black'],
   'group_three': ['white', 'pink','purple','orange']
}
```

Is it an normal js **object** or an **hash** table? If it is not a hash table, then how does the Javascript **hash table** look like?

I can access a group by:

`my_group=groups['group_two']`

Comment: it is an object in javascript.  Not sure if javascript use a hash table to implement it .

Comment: What is the format of hash table in javascript

Comment: same as the object notations. Some will call it associative array ( but be careful , there is no length property to tell the length of the "array" ).

Answer (score 2):

It is an **object**, that's how [specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.6) refers to it. An *object* is a *data type* in JavaScript.

A [**hash table** *<sup>[Wikipedia]</sup>*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) is a *data structure* for which you could use objects, but it does not handle duplicate keys well (it just overrides the entry). You can provide your own implementation, for example have a look at the [Hash Map implementation from the Google Closure Library](https://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_structs_Map.html).

Comment: And Google's Hash Map just uses an object to store and fetch the data.

Comment: Well, eventually any implementation will probably use objects as storage... but after looking at the source code, it does not handle duplicate keys either. It's still an example for an implementation ;)

Comment: It sounds like you took offense.  My comment wasn't meant that way.  I just wanted to show that Google's hash table implementation illustrates that the javascript object has what is needed for the lookup mechanism for a hash table that doesn't allow duplicate keys.

Comment: No offense taken :) Sorry, sometimes I get carried away when commenting ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your `groups` variable refers to a perfectly normal object, which like all normal javascript objects are associative arrays that map property names to property values. These are often implemented as hashtables under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, JavaScript does not have hash tables as such. You have good old zero-based numeric arrays:

```
var a = ["foo", "bar"];
alert(a[0]); // "foo"
```

... and you have objects:

```
var b = {
    x: "foo",
    y: "bar
};
alert(b.x); // "foo"
```

Arrays are sorted by key and cannot have gaps. Objects are not sorted. And they share the square brackets syntax:

```
alert(a[0]);
alert(b[x]); // same as b.x
```

I suppose that JavaScript engines make heavy use of hash tables in their internals but JavaScript engines are not normally written in JavaScript ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the typical capabilities of a hash table, where you provide a key and data and you can then get the data back by providing the key, then a javascript object provides that capability using properties on the object.

Internally to the javascript engine is a property lookup algorithm for objects that likely resembles what is used with a hash table (though the particular implementation is not important as it has the appropriate function).

There is no separate hash table in the language.  One could be implemented, but there is rarely a point as an object typically provides what is needed.

In your data:

```
var groups= {
   'group_one': ['red','green','blue'],
   'group_two': ['yellow','black'],
   'group_three': ['white', 'pink','purple','orange']
}
```

You can access data in the future with:

```
groups.group_one
```

or

```
groups['group_one']
```

and both will evaluate to:

```
['red','green','blue']
```